# Lubridate is creating new a 'year' column, but returning NAs

Tags: r, date

When I do:

```
df2$year <- format(as.Date(df2$DATE, "%m/%d/%y") , "%Y")
```

It returns a columnn called 'year' full of NA's

**data**

```
structure (list(DATE = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1951-01-01", "1951-04-01", "1951-07-01", "1951-10-01", "1952-01-01", "1952-04-01", "1952-07-01", "1952-10-01", "1953-01-01", "1953-04-01", "1953-07-01", [...]), class = "factor"), GPDIC1 = c(300.363, 307.326, 284.697, 262.013, 268.85, 248.58)), .Names = c("DATE", "GPDIC1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: And which lubricate function are you using?

Comment: @Sofia Your `format` is incorrect. In your data it is `1952-01-01` not `1952/01/01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention the format in `as.Date` which is present in your data. In this case, you can directly use `as.Date`

```
df2$year <- format(as.Date(df2$DATE), "%Y")
#Or explicitly mention
#df2$year <- format(as.Date(df2$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y")
```

Or use `year` function from `lubridate`

```
df2$year <- lubridate::year(df2$DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `Date` class with `as.IDate` from `data.table` and extract with `year` from the same package

```
library(data.table)
df2$year <- year(as.IDate(df2$DATE))
```